# Python Beautiful Soup find tag with exact string value of the class

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I tried for hours to find a solution, the code I found either returns all tags that contain one of the classes I try to match, or contains all my classes but with some extra classes in it, but I want the classes to be match EXACTLY.

The following solution didn't work for me as it supposes to:

You can also search for the exact string value of the class attribute:

```
css_soup.find_all("p", class_="body strikeout")
```

I can get the following tag from `HTML sample`, locally, but can't for the page I requested in `Complete code` section:

```
<ul class="mvn listInline">..</ul>
```

HTML sample:

```
<ul class="mvn listInline"> 
    <li class="mbn h4 typeEmphasize">$325,000</li>
    <li class="mbn h7">
         3 bd 2 ba 2,080 sqft 
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="mvn listInline withotherclasses"> 
     <li class="mbn h4 typeEmphasize">$325,000</li>
     <li class="mbn h7">
         3 bd 2 ba 2,080 sqft
     </li>
</ul>

<ul class="mvn onlymvn"> 
     <li class="mbn h4 typeEmphasize">$325,000</li>
     <li class="mbn h7">
         3 bd 2 ba 2,080 sqft
     </li>
</ul>
```

Complete Code:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Anchorage,AK/2_p')
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser') 

for ul in soup_page.find_all("ul", class_="mvn listInline"):
    print ul
```

Comment: Can you provide an example html for which you are facing issue?

Comment: <ul class="mvn listInline"> 
         <li class="mbn h4 typeEmphasize">$325,000</li>
        <li class="mbn h7">
             3 bd 2 ba 2,080 sqft 
        </li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="mvn listInline withotherclasses"> 
         <li class="mbn h4 typeEmphasize">$325,000</li>
        <li class="mbn h7">
             3 bd 2 ba 2,080 sqft
        </li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="mvn onlymvn"> 
         <li class="mbn h4 typeEmphasize">$325,000</li>
        <li class="mbn h7">
             3 bd 2 ba 2,080 sqft
        </li>
     </ul>

Comment: Please update that in the question. Also, update your version for beautifulsoup

Comment: I tried to get only the first ul tag (<ul class="mvn listInline">..</ul>), but failed as the other ul tags will be returned as well.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact code given above? I do not get any issue with that.

Comment: not exact, I will post complete code.

Comment: hm.. It worked for me locally as well

Comment: voting to close since the problem proved to be the relevant code being added by JS.

Answer (score 0):

`soup_page.find_all("ul", class_="mvn listInline")` can only find `ul` with EXACTLY class attributes `mvn listInline` You need to use css selector:
`soup.select("ul.mvn.listInline")`

Comment: That's what I wanted. It works for local html file, but doesn't for the page I requested. Don't know what's the cause. I can see the tag with these two classes in the source inspector.

Comment: @AaronMoose I don't see any elements on that page whose class name is `mvn listInline`. Don't trust inspector. the element/attributes could be added through javascript and there's no way for BeautifulSoup to parse that in this situation.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for helping me out. I will try a different approach to solve my original problem.